# How run mongo command "rs.status" from c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Replica Set, and i want to get rs.status() to analyze it. 
How can i run commands like `rs.status()` from C# driver ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not really familiar with C#, but you can use C#'s [runCommand](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3.1/html/4fe0d8b2-161e-ff83-355d-7517b251d81a.htm) method, keeping in mind that [rs.Status](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-commands/#rs.status) is a wrapper around **replSetGetStatus** database command. Which means you can run it with `db.runCommand({ replSetGetStatus: 1 })`

**P.S.** incorporating irmorteza's comment:

```
var database = mongoServer.GetDatabase("admin"); 
var res = database.RunCommand("replSetGetStatus");
```

Comment: Thanks Salvador. 
var database = mongoServer.GetDatabase("admin");
var res = database.RunCommand("replSetGetStatus");

Comment: in mongo driver version 2.7.2 it expects a <TResult> definition.
database.RunCommand<TResult>("replSetGetStatus");

it gives me an error {"JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'replSetGetStatus'."}

any ideas how to use this method ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201705/mongo-c-sharp-json-reader-was-expecting-a-value-but-found-replsetgetstatus