# Mongo C# JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'replSetGetStatus'

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I was unable to find the proper way to call shell command from Mongo C# driver 
**version 2.7.2**

```
  public async Task RsStatus()
  {
     var res = await _admin.RunCommandAsync<object>("replSetGetStatus");
  }
```

Gives me an the error :

```
  JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'replSetGetStatus'
```

I'm guessing this simply not the way to call shell methods.
Can any one supply me with an example ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db.adminCommand` function expects and object to be passed as a parameter ([here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#dbcmd.replSetGetStatus)) so you can take advantage of `BsonDocumentCommand` generic type and also get a result as a BsonDocument, try:

```
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(
                    new BsonDocument() { { "replSetGetStatus", 1 } });

var res = await _admin.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(command);
```